How can I make the title of this dropdown menu clickable while still keeping the dropdown menu itself?
I have a Bootstrap navbar for a project and now the client wants one of the items to have a dropdown submenu, while still remaining clickable in itself.
I don't have the material time to figure out how to solve this with JQuery because it must be ready today and my knowledge of JQuery requires at least a couple days - so I'm asking you all to help me make this work so that both the main parent link works (when clicked takes to the page "dispositivi.html") AND the dropdown menu also appears on hover.
Below you find the portion of code affected (nothing can be changed as it'd destrupt the rest of the navbar and I don't have the material time to build a new one)
The problem is that, if I use the default "data-toggle" property, the main href itself won't be clickable.
But if I change it to data-hover, as it is now, the dropdown won't appear.
Posted as an image because when I tried to post the code itself it chopped off a lot of it

What version of bootstrap and jquery?

jquery-3.4.1
Bootstrap 4.3.1
